# Do I need to grab every orb?

Tags: seiklus

In seiklus, there are little orbs of various colours that you need to grab as you go along. Some of them I found very hard or frustrating to try to get.

Am I going to be able to finish the game if I miss some of them? I was treating them sort of like coins in Mario games, in the sense that it wasn't necessary to get 100% of them to finish the game. Was this a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to meet up with your girlfriend again, yeah. There should be 100 of each... six, excluding the white ones. The white ones are optional... do them after you get all the other (main) colors.

There's another ending waiting for you if you get 100%...

Comment: I was afraid of that. Hopefully I can go back and get what I missed.